# List files a command opens? lsof is too slow

Tags: files, lsof, macos

Is there some utility, that I can run a certain command A "within", that lists all files A opens while executing?

I run a utility (A) that changes some password requirements and something is broket. Therefore  I need to manually open the changed file and see the conent. This command finishes in a second or so so `lsof` is too slow for the purpose.

Comment: On Linux, you would be able to use `strace` I believe, to see, among other things, what files it opens.

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I am on a Mac. Updated the question now. I don't have strace.

Comment: @NickD How do I exeute that fast enough for a command that finishes more or less instantaneously?

Comment: As well as `strace` I have used `find` to list all very recently changed files (it only work if the system is not heavenly loaded (As you would get lots of false positives from other processes).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to trace the system calls made by the program, and filter for `open`/`openat` system calls, or name lookup.

The original two tools for this were `truss` on AT&T Unix System 5 and `ktrace` on 4.4BSD.  (The latter pairs `ktrace` with `kdump` which translates the machine-readable output to human-readable form.)  A later invention, a couple of decades afterwards, was the DTrace framework.

So nowadays, to trace the execution for some command `wibble`:

- On Illumos and related operating systems, the utility for this is [`truss`](https://illumos.org/man/truss) inherited via SunOS. e.g.

  ```
  truss -o truss.out -t open,openat wibble
  ```
- On OpenBSD, the utility for this is [`ktrace`](http://man.openbsd.org/ktrace) from 4.4BSD, with [`kdump`](http://man.openbsd.org/kdump). e.g.

  ```
  ktrace -t n wibble
  ```
- On MacOS, the utility for this is `dtruss`.  e.g.

  ```
  dtruss -t open wibble
  ```
- On Linux-based operating systems, the utility for this is [`strace`](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/strace/strace.1.en.html). e.g.

  ```
  strace -o strace.out -e open,openat wibble
  ```
- FreeBSD and its derivative operating systems have both:

  - a clone of AT&T [`truss`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=truss), which however lacks the `-t` option of the original, meaning that you will have to post-process things with the usual text-processing tools; and
  - the [`ktrace`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ktrace) (plus [`kdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kdump)) from 4.4BSD, which does support `-t n`.

FreeBSD and Illumos, and their derivatives, also have `dtrace` et al. as part of the DTrace framework, but that's overkill for your particular purposes here.  MacOS `dtruss` is in fact built upon the DTrace framework, which is why it requires superuser privileges, a drawback that none of the other tools mentioned here have.

Comment: `% sudo dtruss -t open pwpolicy -getglobalpolicy             
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

dtrace: failed to execute pwpolicy: (os/kern) failure`