# How to trace and print out all files that are accessed / used when bash starts?

Tags: bash, macos, dtrace

I'm having a problem and need to print out to the console all files that are being access each time `bash` is executed on macOS.

Is there a relatively easy method for doing this? Perhaps `dtrace` might make this fairly straight forward?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/560460/5132 .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all the files that any process named 'bash' opens directly, you can do something like this:

```
$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry/execname == "bash"/{ trace(copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

You may, alternatively, want to see all the files opened between when bash starts and you get to the prompt. For that, you could do something like this:

```
$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry/progenyof($target)/{ printf("%s %s", execname, copyinstr(arg0)) }' -c bash
```

Note that this will show both the file being opened as well as the command accessing it.